# How to overloading operator= in red-black tree? C++

Tags: c++, assignment-operator, red-black-tree

I have a red-black tree that needs to be overloaded with an assignment operator. I kind of overloaded the operator= of a binary tree whose nodes don't know their parents. But how do I do this for a tree where nodes have a relationship with the left, right, and parent?

```
template<typename KEY, typename VALUE> class map;
template <typename KEY, typename VALUE>
class Node
{
private:
    friend class map<KEY, VALUE>;
 
    KEY id;
    VALUE object;
    bool color;
 
    Node* parent;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;
 
    Node(): id(0), object(nullptr), color(RED), parent(nullptr), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}
    Node(const KEY& id, const VALUE& object) : id(id), object(object), color(RED), parent(nullptr), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}
};
 
template<typename KEY, typename VALUE>
class map
{
private:
    Node<KEY, VALUE>* root;
public:
        map() : root(nullptr) {}
    ~map() { destroy(root); }
 
    map(const map<KEY, VALUE>& other)
    {
        if (other.root == nullptr)
            root = nullptr;
        else
            copyTree(root, other.root);
    }
 
    const map<KEY, VALUE>& operator=(const map<KEY, VALUE>& other)
    {
        if (this != &other)
        {
            if (root != nullptr)
                destroy(root);
            if (other.root == nullptr)
                root = NULL;
            else
                copyTree(root, other.root);
        }
        return *this;
    }
 
    void copyTree (Node<KEY, VALUE>*& copiedTreeRoot, Node<KEY, VALUE>* otherTreeRoot)
    {
        if (otherTreeRoot == nullptr)
            copiedTreeRoot = nullptr;
        else {
            copiedTreeRoot = new Node<KEY, VALUE>;
            copiedTreeRoot->id = otherTreeRoot->id;
            copiedTreeRoot->object = otherTreeRoot->object;
            copiedTreeRoot->color = otherTreeRoot->color;
            copiedTreeRoot->parent = otherTreeRoot->parent;
            copyTree(copiedTreeRoot->left, otherTreeRoot->left);
            copyTree(copiedTreeRoot->right, otherTreeRoot->right);
            //copyTree(copiedTreeRoot->parent, otherTreeRoot->parent);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: I'd start by adding a copy constructor to `Node` so you can move all that out of your `copyTree` function. If `other.root == nullptr` and you've done `destroy(root)` before it, I guess `root` still points at a now destroyed `Node`? So, what does your `destroy` function look like? Please make a [mcve].

Comment: I'd recommend to not call your class `map`, because it may be confused with `std::map`. Particularly, if you have to include a header containing a `using namespace std` you'll have a problem.

Comment: @TedLyngmo ok, here: https://github.com/insania37/binatyTree

Comment: @bjhend This is a temporary name :)

Comment: @insania37 Put a [mcve] in the question instead of linking to it.

Comment: @insania37 Temporary solutions always last longer than expected, even when considering this.

Comment: @bjhend: Eiffel tower was temporary... And still there in Paris.

Comment: @insania37 -- Check the answer showing you how to simply create the assignment operator using `std::swap`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might pass new parent to `CopyTree`:

```
const map<KEY, VALUE>& operator=(const map<KEY, VALUE>& other)
{
    if (this != &other)
    {
        if (root != nullptr)
            destroy(root);
        copyTree(root, nullptr, other.root);
    }
    return *this;
}

void copyTree (Node<KEY, VALUE>*& copiedTreeRoot,
               Node<KEY, VALUE>* newParent,
               Node<KEY, VALUE>* otherTreeRoot)
{
    if (otherTreeRoot == nullptr)
        copiedTreeRoot = nullptr;
    else {
        copiedTreeRoot = new Node<KEY, VALUE>;
        copiedTreeRoot->id = otherTreeRoot->id;
        copiedTreeRoot->object = otherTreeRoot->object;
        copiedTreeRoot->color = otherTreeRoot->color;
        copiedTreeRoot->parent = newParent;

        copyTree(copiedTreeRoot->left, copiedTreeRoot, otherTreeRoot->left);
        copyTree(copiedTreeRoot->right, copiedTreeRoot, otherTreeRoot->right);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have a working copy constructor and destructor, you can utilize [copy / swap idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom):

```
#include <algorithm>
//...
const map<KEY, VALUE>& operator=(const map<KEY, VALUE>& other)
{
     if (this != &other)
     {
        map<KEY, VALUE> temp(other);
        std::swap(temp.root, root);
     }
     return *this;
}
```

This works due to simply creating a temporary `map` copied from `other`, and simply swapping out the current contents.

The flaw with your original code is that you destroyed the root, but you have no idea if the `new` in `copytree` will not `throw`.  If that happens, you've corrupted your map.

Using copy/swap, a temporary is created -- if anything throws from creating the temporary, then your original `map` won't get corrupted.

Comment: The copy constructor isn't working for the same reason as the assignation: OP has issue to assign parents with `CopyTree`.

Comment: Yes, this works, but the `CopyTree` is still required for the copy constructor. The problem was with him.